# Ideas on the Limits of BitmapRegionDecoder

Tags: java, android, graphics, skia

Recently I have started running into memory issues with BitmapRegionDecoder. Odd, yes, as it is designed to only read parts in and those parts I want are usually 100-200 pixels by 100-200 pixels.

My question is: where are the limits on the size of image you can use with BitmapRegionDecoder? E.g., I am having issues with a 50,000x30,000 JPEG that's around 500 MB total. (This is a high res map, hence the size.)